# Scrapy yield does not display any results

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy & Python. Just following a tutorial for building a scraper.

I wrote the following code:

```
import scrapy


class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"
    allowed_domains = ['blog.scrapinghub.com']

    start_urls = [
        'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.css('div.post-item'):
            yield {
                'title': post.css('.post-header h2 a::text')[0].get(),
                'date': post.css('.post-header a::text')[1].get(),
                'author': post.css('.post-header a::text')[2].get()
            }
        next_page = response.css('a.next-posts-link::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

The code just executes without any error, but nothing is printed. On debug I see that it is not going inside the parse method. Help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for your problem can not be derived from your code. I just executed your spider-code in my scrape-project to test it and for me it runs perfectly fine without a single change to it. I correctly get the title, date and author for all 17 pages of that blog printed to the terminal.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was running this as a normal python program. I ran it now as '''scrapy crawl posts''' Now it works

Answer (score 1):

The content you trying to get might be auto generated via javascript. An approach to this problem is using a headless-browser such as [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or [splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Their job is to load the page as a regular browser, so the complete content should be there!

I recommend you to use splash for 2 reasons:

- It's lighter;
- It's made by the scrapy team;

Consider using the [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) project, so it'll be easier to integrate project with splash.

Answer (score 0):

In python, correctly indenting code is very important. The way you wrote your code, you haven't indented your instance variables and methods correctly inside your spider class. You need to add the proper indentation in order for this code to work.

Something like this:

```
import scrapy

class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"
    allowed_domains = ['blog.scrapinghub.com']

    start_urls = [
        'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.css('div.post-item'):
            yield {
                'title': post.css('.post-header h2 a::text')[0].get(),
                'date': post.css('.post-header a::text')[1].get(),
                'author': post.css('.post-header a::text')[2].get()
            }
        next_page = response.css('a.next-posts-link::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. Its an indentation error in the code pasted in the question. I copy pasted the code that you had shared. The results are the same.